# Como contar y mostrar datos repetidos de mysql con nodejs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, ejs

Soy nuevo en NodeJS y estuve practicando, cree un formulario que ingresa los siguientes valores Nombre, Servicio, Código y Fecha de finalización en la base de datos, los cuales seran mostrados en una tabla con ejs, la tabla esta compuesta por Nombre, Servicio, Codigo, Veces usado y Fecha de finalización, mi problema es el siguiente el "Codigo" es un valor que puede repetirse entre varios usuarios y en la celda "Veces usado" debe mostrarse el numero de veces que se repite en la base de datos pero no se como hacerlo, estuve investigando y para eso debo usar count() de mysql pero no tengo muy entendido en que parte del codigo debo implementarlo.

este es el codigo que uso para mostrar los datos de la base de datos en ejs

```
controller.list = (req, res) => {
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios", (err, usuarios) => {
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }
        res.render("usuarios", {
            data: usuarios
        })
    })  
})
```

}

y este es el codigo en ejs para mostrar los datos en html

```
            <tbody class="information">
                <% if (data) { %>
                    <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= (i+1) %></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].nombre%></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].tipo_de_servicio %></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].codigo %></td>
                            <td>aqui va el numero de veces que se repite</td>
                            <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).format(shortDateFormat)%></td>
                            <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).diff(moment(), "hour") %> horas </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/delete/<%= data[i].id %>" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</a>
                                <a href="/update/<%= data[i].id %>" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debería bastar

```
SELECT 
    col, 
    COUNT(col)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY col
HAVING COUNT(col) > 1
```

Acá lo que hacemos es recorrer por grupos determinados, que en este caso sería Código y va contando cuantas veces está sobre la tabla, y después realizamos la condición de *sólo mayor a 1*.

Nos comentas si te sirve :D

Comment: si me sirve, pero tengo una consulta en que parte del codigo ingreso esto SELECT 
    col, 
    COUNT(col)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY col
HAVING COUNT(col) > 1 , eso es lo que no entiendo muy bien, lo hago en los controladores? o como?

Comment: Ignoro la arquitectura en la que estás trabajando, pero según tu publicación, sólo deberías reemplazar `SELECT * FROM` por el código de la respuesta.